# How to solve UnknownHostException error in google spreadsheet using the API?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

To develope a client applications, I need to read and modify worksheets and data in `Google Sheets`. I am facing with below issue:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("sheet1");
String sheetUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1XP3KQTboWCArbvH99XYEGsVOldc97NqFzKD MiEepXRA/default/public/values"; //Sheet url             
URL url = new URL(sheetUrl); // Get Feed of Spreadsheet url 
ListFeed lf = service.getFeed(url, ListFeed.class); //Error statement
```

Issue:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: spreadsheets.google.com    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:503)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
>     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:631)
>     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)   at
>   test_project.test_demo.main(test_demo.java:35)

Comment: Unknown host usually means your URL is wrong...are you sure it isn't just sheets.google.com or something else?

Comment: It might not be a duplicate. Is your project java 7 or 8 ? In case of java 8 the default appengine-web.xml settings can cause that exception when billing is not enabled. Please have a look at url-stream-handler at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/acra-discuss/nNrkqXgA1t0), [**`UnknownHostException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/UnknownHostException.html?hl=el) means that your device was not able to resolve the host name. It emerges when you are trying to connect to a remote host using its host name, but the IP address of that host cannot be resolved. From this [blog](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/unknownhostexception/java-net-unknownhostexception-how-to-solve-unknownhostexception/), you should check the input of Socket (or any other method that throws an `UnknownHostException`), and validate that it is the intended one. If you are not sure whether you have the correct host name, you can launch a terminal and use the `nslookup` command to see if your DNS server can resolve the host name to an IP address successfully.

If that doesn’t work, you should check if the host name you have is correct and then try to refresh your DNS cache. If that doesn’t work either, try to use a different DNS server, eg `Google Public DNS` is a very good alternative.

You can also check on this [link](http://www.awasthiashish.com/2015/10/read-data-from-google-spreadsheet.html#sthash.tbVzLggQ.dpbs). Hope this helps!